# Hatcher Exercise 2.2.38

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

[image]

I'm struggling to show exactness at $C_n\oplus D_n$. Let's take $(x,y)\in C_n\oplus D_n$ in the kernel of $C_n\oplus D_n\to E_n$, i.e. the pushforwards $x', y'$ into $E_n$ resp. satisfy $x' + y' = 0$. We need to find a pre-image of $(x,y)$ in $B_n$.

By exactness of the bottom, $y'$ pushed forward to $A_{n-1}$ gives $0$ (two steps in an exact sequence). Then $x'=-y'$ also goes to $0$, hence $x$ goes to $0$ by commutativity. Then $x$ has a pre-image $x_1\in B_n$.

I'm stuck here. Am I on the right track? How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indeed on the right track. $x_1$ already has the correct image in $C_n$, but unfortunately maybe not in $D_n$, so we need to correct $x_1$ with something, such that the image in $C_n$ stays untouched and the image in $D_n$ is the right one.

Call the image of $x_1$ in $D_n$ $d$. The image of $d$ in $E_n$ is $x'=-y'$, hence $d+y$ is zero in $E_n$, so it comes from $A_n$. Now try to proceed using the element in $A_n$ to correct $x_1$ in such a way it maps to $y$ in $D_n$.

Comment my answer, if you are not able to finish it by yourself and I'll help you.

Comment: Right, $d+y$ is zero in $E_n$, so it has a pre-image in $A_n$, call it $a$. Pushing $a$ forward to $B_n$ gives an element $a'$ which is mapped to $d+y$ in $D_n$. But then $a'-x_1$ goes to $y$ in $D_n$. Moreover, if we push $a'-x_1$ into $C_n$, we get $-x$ since $a'$ will be zero (two steps in exact sequence). So then $a'-x_1$ is the desired element.

Comment: If you don't mind, I have another question regarding the other inclusion. That is, let $(x,y)\in C_n\oplus D_n$ have a pre-image $b$ in $B_n$. Pushing $b$ into $E_n$ via $C_n$ adds a minus, so it gives exactly the additive inverse of the pushforward via $D_n$, right? I.e. $(x,y)$ maps to zero under the map $C_n\oplus D_n\to E_n$.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: By the way, almost all kind of Mayer-Vietoris-like long exact sequences trace back to that homological lemma. At least if you want to derive them from long exact sequences you already know instead of constructing them directly, e.g. with the help of a short exact sequence on the level of chain complexes.

Comment: Interesting. In fact, the next exercise is to derive the relative Mayer-Vietoris sequence for CW pairs from the above lemma. I'm working on it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Homological Algebra is a game of arrows, if you can fully make use of the arrows, you can prove theorems.

First of all, let us define $\sigma_{AB}, \sigma_{AD}, \sigma_{BD}, \sigma_{BC}, \sigma_{CE}, \sigma_{DE}$ be maps of corresponding arrows. Let   $$B_n \xrightarrow{\phi} C_n \oplus D_n\xrightarrow{\epsilon}E_n$$
with  $$\phi=\sigma_{BC} \oplus (-\sigma_{BD}),\\ \epsilon=\sigma_{CE} \oplus \sigma_{DE}$$

Now, it is obvious that $ker\epsilon=\{(c,d)\in C_n \oplus D_n: \sigma_{CE}(c)+\sigma_{DE}(d)=0   \}$,and $Im\phi \subset ker\epsilon$, what we should do is to show that $Im\phi \supset ker\epsilon$.

Step1, let $(c,d)\in ker\epsilon$, we have $\sigma_{CE}(c)=-\sigma_{DE}(d)=\sigma_{DE}(-d)$, and then apply $\sigma_{EA}$, we have $0=\sigma_{EA}\circ\sigma_{DE}(-d)=\sigma_{EA}\circ\sigma_{CE}(c)=\sigma_{CA}(c)$ by the communtativity of the diagram. Now by the exactness of above complex, we have $\exists b\in B_n$, s.t. $\sigma_{BC}(b)=c.$

Step2, consider the element $\Delta=\sigma_{BD}(b)+d\in D_n$, apply $\sigma_{DE}$ to $\Delta$, we have $\sigma_{DE}(\Delta)=\sigma_{DE}(\sigma_{BD}(b)+d)=\sigma_{DE}\circ\sigma_{BD}(b)+\sigma_{DE}(d)=\sigma_{CE}\circ\sigma_{BE}(b)+\sigma_{DE}(d)=\sigma_{CE}(c)+\sigma_{DE}(d)=0$. Therefore $\Delta\in ker\sigma_{DE}=Im\sigma_{AD}$, and so $\exists a\in A_n$, s.t. $\sigma_{AD}(a)=\Delta$

Step3, consider the element $\beta=\sigma_{AB}(a)-b\in B_n$. You can check that $\beta$ is the element such that $\phi(\beta)=(c,d)$.

Q.E.D.